# java save changes

Tags: java, swing, observer-pattern, jlist, savechanges

I have an application which consists mainly in a `JList` being displayed on the screen. I would like that everytime I make a change to the `AbstractListModel`(adding or removing items to the list) , to somehow notify the app that changes have been made and modify the `JFrame`'s title to something like `frame_title[unsaved]`. After I would save the app, the `[unsaved]` tag would go away.

I think maybe using the observer/observable technique would do the job but I am not sure how to do it. Maybe there is something much more appropriate to my problem? I am new to java new to java so that is why I came here asking for help. Thanks.

UPDATE : I can't really use the Observer-pattern in my case because I am already extending the `AbstractListModel` class.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to Observer your `AbstractListModel` extension ? Each `ListModel` has a mechanism to add listeners to it, or the `JList` would not work. So you are perfectly capable of observing any `ListModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
AbstractListModel model = ...;
model.addListDataListener(new ListDataListener() {
    public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {

    }

    public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {

    }

    public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {

    }
});
```